JBOSS EAP 7.4.16 not working with openjdk17 showing .jacc is missing
Its working fine with JBOSS EAP 7.4.0 and openjdk17 but when i migrated to 7.4.16, im facing this issue.
org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm and jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management services are not installed
What would be the cause. Im getting org.wildfly.legacy-security.jacc are not installed.

Legacy security does not work with Java SE 17. Please note this is behind a paywall, but given you're using JBoss EAP 7.4.16 I assume you've got paid support https://access.redhat.com/articles/6956863.
